# Find required Java modules

Tags: java, encoding, java-module

We build our own jigsawed JRE for our application (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060773/essential-jigsawed-java-9-jre-without-modularized-code)), but some (character) encodings are missing compared to run the application with a full JRE.

How to find our what module is missing to get all the encodings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are missing [`jdk.localedata` module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk.localedata-summary.html). As per docs:

> Provides the locale data for locales other than US locale.

You can view all modules in your JDK by running `java --list-modules` and try additional modules if this is not enough.

Comment: Are you sure? Not `jdk.charsets`?

Comment: or both, there is not enough information in your question. You might be right with `jdk.charsets` but you should have tests to prove that it works.